# I've created a function in C++ to reverse a string recursively, but how can I make the funtion print a endl afterwards?

Tags: c++, recursion

This is in C++ The original prompt was to create a recursive function that reverses a string. The function works, but I am not sure how to get `endl` IN the function after it reverses the string so it looks good in console. This works:

```
string reverse(string str) {
    if (str.size() == 1) {
        return str;
    }
    string str2 = reverse(str.substr(1));
    return str2 + str[0];
}
```

Comment: normally you would *not* have a new line in a string

Comment: You can't. You do the printing outside the function.

Comment: NB [tag:optimization] has nothing to do with it.

Comment: I consider your recursion code well done.  Kudos.  I also like your question.

Answer (score 2):

What about doing this:

```
string str="Hello";
cout << reverse(str) << endl;
```

Here you will reverse the string, print it, and then start a new line.

You can place a newline inside by utilizing the last character index like this:

```
string reverse(string str, int length) {
    if (str.size() == 1) {
        return str;
    }
    string str2 = reverse(str.substr(1), length);
    // if are at the last character, we just insert a newline after it
    if(length == str2.length())
    {
        return str2 + str[0] + '\n';
    }
    return str2 + str[0];
}


int main()
{
    string str = "Hello";
    // we get position of last character
    cout << reverse(str, str.length() -1);

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: I am looking for a way to ```endl``` IN the function

Comment: @runrocks I am updating my answer with a solution. Once we reach the length of the original string we can add the newline character after.

Answer (score 0):

You can prepend new line character to your string argument before passing it to the `reverse()` function,

```c
string str {"Hello"};

str = "\n" + str;

cout << reverse(str);
```

If you want to do this in the `reverse` function definition, you need to keep track of the depth of recursion so you can prepend the new line character in the first level of recursion,

```c
string reverse(string str, int depth = 0) {

    if(depth==0) {
        str = "\n" + str;
    }

    depth++;

    if(str.size() == 1) {
        return str;
    }
    string str2 = reverse(str.substr(1), depth);
    return str2 + str[0];
}
```

Answer (score 0):

> how to get endl IN the function after it reverses the string so it
> looks good in console.

For your consideration, reverse2() (below, the last function) has

```
a) half the recursions

b) appends an eoln char
```

---

```
#include <algorithm>
using std::swap;

#include <iostream>
using std::cout, std::endl, std::flush;

#include <string>
using std::string, std::to_string;


// forward declarations
string reverse (string str); // from this post, with fix
//
string reverse2 (string str);


void test1(string s)
{
   cout << "\n  s1: " << s
        << "\n  r1: " << reverse(s);
   cout <<   "  -----" << endl;     // highlight lack of eoln
}

void test2(string s)
{
   cout << "\n  s2: " << s
        << "\n  r2: " << reverse2(s);
   cout <<   "  -----";              // highlight eoln appended!
}


int main(int , char** )
{
   int retVal = 0;

   test1("123456789");
   test1("12345678");
   test1("123");
   test1("45");
   test1("6");
   test1("");  // empty string 

   test2("987654321");
   test2("87654321");
   test2("321");
   test2("54");
   test2("6");
   test2("");  // empty string

   return retVal;
}


// implementation from OP's post (with fix for empty string)
string reverse (string str)
{
 //if (str.size() == 1) { // fails test case (0 == str.size())

   if (str.size() < 2)  { // fix
      return str;
   }
   string str2 = reverse(str.substr(1));
   return str2 + str[0];
}


// recursive alternative to consider
//                            left    right indx
void reverseR (string& s, int l,  int r)
{  //                 \|
   //            swaps s elements in-place
   if ((r - l) >= 0)          // recursion termination clause
   {
      swap(s[static_cast<uint>(l)],
           s[static_cast<uint>(r)]);  // modify s in place
      reverseR (s, l+1, r-1);         // recursively call
   }
}

// append eoln
string reverse2 (string str) // stack copy, modified-in-place-here
{  // index:      v--left         right--vvvvvvvvvvvvvv
   reverseR (str, 0,    (static_cast<int>(str.size()-1))); // recursive swaps
   return (str + '\n');     // return result + eoln
}
```

Output:

```
  s1: 123456789
  r1: 987654321  -----

  s1: 12345678
  r1: 87654321  -----

  s1: 123
  r1: 321  -----

  s1: 45
  r1: 54  -----

  s1: 6
  r1: 6  -----

  s1: 
  r1:   -----

  s2: 987654321
  r2: 123456789
  -----
  s2: 87654321
  r2: 12345678
  -----
  s2: 321
  r2: 123
  -----
  s2: 54
  r2: 45
  -----
  s2: 6
  r2: 6
  -----
  s2: 
  r2: 
  -----
```

---

Update - 2020/06/08

FYI - I have briefly captured some performance measurements.

I measured these on my 8 yr old (and slow) Dell, with Lubuntu 20.04, and g++ v9.3.0.

- Your code (reverse())
  can process      461,175  50-element strings in 2999 ms
- Something very similar to my code (reverse2())
  can process   13,783,340  50 element strings in 3000 ms
- and std::reverse, wrapped in a conforming function (but not recursive)
  can process   15,917,504  50 element strings in 2999 ms

---

IMHO, the primary difference between reverse() and reverse2() is the number of times a string is passed during the recursion.

I do not know much about std::reverse(), but I'm impressed with its performance.

Comment: This code appends a '\n' char to the reverse2() string.  Using it avoids un-necessary overhead of stream output to a console (i.e. buffer flush, etc).  It is likely you can find a 'better' location in your code to send a full eoln, and won't need the extra overhead for most of these..